# Connect Pouch Db mobile app to .net

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, cordova, pouchdb

I need to connect my PouchDB mobile app to my .net api, for sync databases. I'n my pouchdb, Ionic, Cordova app I haves This connection strings.

```
 WebServicesURL:         'https://localhost:44302/api/',
 WebServicesURLHTTPS:    'https://localhost:44302/api/',
 LocalDatabaseName:      'CBRE_Opus_Local',
 MaxPhotosPerQuestion:   4,
 MaxPhotosForInspection: 40,
```

and I need the correct way of connection, to connect to my Api.

Comment: You must clarify your question. You want to sync your with CouchDB?